# How can I send an internal View to an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I put them in context. I currently have a web application which, to put it simply, has a dropdown list, and when you select an option and click a button called "Submit", it redirects you to another page with a form.

What they asked me now is that when I select an option, remove the button and instead of redirecting, the corresponding form is loaded below the drop-down list.

From what I was seeing, with Javascript there is fetch(), but it points to an API, and I need a form that I have inside my project to be loaded, that is, it is not an API, do I explain?

What I tried to do is, to use an iframe to send the form view, but I don't know how to send the `iframe` the view I need to show

I wanted to know if you could help me with this, because I have low levels of knowledge with HTML and CSS.

This is my form. What occurs to me is to put each form below this one, but I find it impractical.

This is my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <form action="/Home/Opcion" method="post" id="form" class="form">
                <div class="col-6 mx-auto mb-4 mt-5">
                    <label class="form-label" for="formulario">Elija un Formulario:</label>
                        <select id="formulario" class="form-select" name="formulario" title="Formulario" onchange="mostrarFormulario(this.value)" required>
                        <option value="">Elija una opción</option>
                        <option value="DEC.cshtml">DEC</option>
                        <option value="lfd">LFD</option>
                        <option value="sac">SAC</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="col-12 buttonSubmit">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
function mostrarFormulario(valor) {
    console.log(valor);
    document.getElementById("Contenedor").src = valor
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged with reactjs, but I do not see any reacjs code. Do you want to solve this with plain javascript or react?

Comment: You are right, I didn't use reactjs here but for what I understand for what I'm trying to do, using Reactjs should be the best option